# python: Update values of dictionary recursively

Tags: python, string, dictionary, recursion, format

Using python 3.7, I have a dictionary which can have values either as strings, dictionaries or list of strings or list of dictionaries. Here is an example:

```
{
    "about_me": {
        "age": "{age}"
    },
    "name": {
        "full_name": {
            "first": "{first_name}",
            "last": "{last_name}"
        }
    },
    "addresses": [{
        "home": "{home_address}"
    }, {
        "work": "{work_address}"
    }],
    "phones": [
        "{home_phone}",
        "{work_phone}"
    ]
}
```

The values are in a JSON like this:

```
{
    "{age}": 25,
    "{first_name}": "Robert",
    "{last_name}": "Miles",
    "{home_address}": "123 Main St, CA 90111",
    "{work_address}": "456 Wall St, CA 00871",
    "{home_phone}": "18008008001",
    "{work_phone}": "18008018011"
}
```

Here is the expected JSON:

```
{
    "about_me": {
        "age": "25"
    },
    "name": {
        "full_name": {
            "first": "Robert",
            "last": "Miles"
        }
    },
    "addresses": [{
        "home": "123 Main St, CA 90111"
    }, {
        "work": "456 Wall St, CA 00871"
    }],
    "phones": [
        "18008008001",
        "18008018011"
    ]
}
```

Example: 
All I am trying to do is inject the values recursively into the "about_me" dictionary. Example below:

```
person = {
    'first':'Robert',
    'last': 'Miles',
    'age':25
}
print('{first} {last} is {age} years old'.format(**person))
> Robert Miles is 25 years old
```

What I've tried so far is good for strings, dictionaries and list of dictionaries. It falls apart for dictionary of dictionaries (x n levels).

Comment: Just to make sure I understood the problem here. You have a dictionary that can be nested with strings, lists, or other dictionaries. You want to find a sub dictionary that is called `'abbout me'` and then inject a dictionary in it?

Comment: 2 dictionaries: nested dictionary is "about_me" and flat dictionary is "values". Im trying to inject "values" dictionary into "about_me". Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use recursion with a dictionary comprehension:

```
data = {'about_me': {'age': '{age}'}, 'name': {'full_name': {'first': '{first_name}', 'last': '{last_name}'}}, 'addresses': [{'home': '{home_address}'}, {'work': '{work_address}'}], 'phones': ['{home_phone}', '{work_phone}']}
l = {'{age}': 25, '{first_name}': 'Robert', '{last_name}': 'Miles', '{home_address}': '123 Main St, CA 90111', '{work_address}': '456 Wall St, CA 00871', '{home_phone}': '18008008001', '{work_phone}': '18008018011'}
def update(d):
  if not isinstance(d, (dict, list)):
     return l.get(d, d)
  return {a:update(b) if isinstance(b, dict) else list(map(update, b)) if isinstance(b, list)
        else l.get(b, b) for a, b in d.items()}
```

---

```
import json
print(json.dumps(update(data), indent=4))
```

Output:

```
{
  "about_me": {
    "age": 25
   },
   "name": {
    "full_name": {
        "first": "Robert",
        "last": "Miles"
    }
  },
  "addresses": [
    {
        "home": "123 Main St, CA 90111"
    },
    {
        "work": "456 Wall St, CA 00871"
    }
 ],
  "phones": [
     "18008008001",
     "18008018011"
   ]
}
```

Comment: Confirmed working @Ajax1234. A curve ball though - if one of the values is a static string that does not have to be mapped/replaced... for instance if "about_me" had additional key "status": "active" (active is not available in "values" dictionary). Currently it gives a KeyError: 'active'. Could you propose/edit the solution?

Comment: @cloudjockey In that case the best approach is to use `dict.get`. Please see my recent edit.

Comment: Worked, but replaced the `return l.get(d, d)` with `return d.format_map(l)` because some of the strings could use .format_map() for instance: `home_address`: `{home_address}{country}`. Same with `l.get(b, b)` using `b.format_map(l)`. My original question didn't mention it, but made it more generic. I have accepted your answer!